# Git pushed, but when I pull is does not pull it as a project

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I created a maven project in eclipse and pushed it to a remote branch. When I pulled it from another computer I did not get it as a project, I only got the folder structure. That is what I see in eclipse, the folder structure, not the project packages.

Was I supposed to commit with some files that are usually ignored, like a .project file? (I have not set anything to be ignored...)

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shared the `.project` file and on the other computer the project not imported via right-click and _Import Projects..._ in the _Git Repositories_ view or via _File > Open Projects from File System..._. Or on the other computer Maven support is missing. Show the `.project` files of both computers to find the real cause.

Comment: Good point. I actually just figured it out and added an answer. ( I over looked something silly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, I have a root project that has a bunch of smaller projects attached to it, with this new project not attached by the pom. So when I imported the root, the new project never came over. Something silly I overlooked.

Because this new project is stored in under the root project but not referenced in the root project's pom, I needed to manually import it. (which in my case, I need to keep the project out of the root pom, it should not build when the root builds...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to add files first and then commit it with some message and then push to the remote branch

here are some pointers

```
git branch
```

this will show you on which branch you are working on

```
git status
```

this will show you which files are added to the stage (i.e. ready to commit) and which are not tracked

```
git add {filenames}
```

this will add files in the stage area.

```
git commit
```

staged files get committed but not available on a remote branch yet

```
git push origin {remoteBranchName}
```

this will push the files to the remote branch.

you can validate this through UI or through git pull on other machine.

Comment: Thank you for the description, its nicely laid out. I should have been more clear above. I have all my files when I pull. I just do not see it as a project in the new computer. Eclipse only shows a folder structure, not a maven project.

Comment: I ended up finding the issue. I added an answer. But thank you for your answer, it is very well written out.